# How to substitute a specific value in the DOM with a single jQuery call

Tags: javascript, jquery

Throughout the DOM I have values (innerHTML) that I want to replace.

For example

```
<div id="id1">N/A</div>
...
...
<div id="id2">N/A</div>
...
...
<div id="id3">n/a</div>
...
...
```

and I want to substitute if with a 0.

How do I do this with a single jQuery call?

**CLARIFYING QUESTION**
I want to select those elements that have N/A or n/a as values (innerHTML), regardless of if they are in a `div`, a `span`, a `td`...

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? selecting, or changing the text. Both have already been answered on SO.

Comment: Selecting all elements that have a N/A or n/a as the value.

Comment: so, in other words, you want to select all elements that *contain* some particular text. have you considered using the *:contains* selector?

Comment: @KevinB PERFECT!!! Do you want to add your answer?

Answer (score 0):

If all of the replacements you want to do are for `div` elements you can try this:

```
$("div").html('0');
```

You didn't specify any constraints so I based my answer on what you posted.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to use an [attribute selector](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/CSS/Attribute_selectors.html):

```
$('[id^="id"]').text('0');
```

If you only want the ones with "N/A" in the text, you would need to loop over all of the divs and check for the "N/A" text.

```
$('[id^="id"]').each(function(){
   var $t=$(this), txt =$t.text();
   if (txt.toLowerCase() === 'n/a') { //convert to lowercase to match regardless of capitalization
     $t.text('0');
   }
});
```

Comment: why not `$("#id").text('0');` ?

Comment: @happymacarts because it wouldn't do anything?

Comment: @happymacarts  `$('#id')`  would only match the one item.  The attribute selector in the above code finds any ID that starts with the letters "id".

Comment: @Gary very well . i guess the OP is not very clear which one(s) he wants

Comment: @Kevin B when i asked #id i meant that to be = to the one he was targeting. i guess we had different interpretations of what the OP was asking for